# How to Kill a Timer in Python Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

The standard way to end `ontimer()` in Python Turtle Graphics is to simply not repeat calling it, based on some condition.

In my use case however, I need to actively kill the timer.

The relevent part of code from the `turtle` module is:

```
    def _ontimer(self, fun, t):
        """Install a timer, which calls fun after t milliseconds.
        """
        if t == 0:
            self.cv.after_idle(fun)
        else:
            self.cv.after(t, fun)
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776718/how-do-i-stop-tkinter-after-function) explains how to destroy a timer using pure `python tkinter`. I found the `after` method in `turtle._Root` but I can't see how to get access to the `id` for it, or figure out exactly how I would use it if I had it.

Any help much appredciated.

Here's a sample program I would like to apply the solution to:

```
import turtle

turtle.shape("turtle")

def move():
    turtle.fd(20)
    turtle.ontimer(move, 500)

move()

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter after\_cancel in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25702094/tkinter-after-cancel-in-python). Avoid the term `kill`, read [Is there any way to kill a Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread)

Comment: As according to the code in `turtle` module, `ontimer()` is actually using `tkinter.after` function internally.  So you can directly use `after_id = turtle.getcanvas().after(500, move)` instead of `turtle.ontimer(...)` and then use `.after_cancel(after_id)` to cancel the timer task.