# tkinter custom progressbar going back and forth

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a custom progress bar, the mechamism I'm trying to figure out at the moment is how can I set back or fast-forward the progressbar's progress by clicking or holding the left mouse button to the desired positon. The problem, I'm facing is that when I set back or fast-forward the bar, the bar's progress goes back and forth, this probably has to do with the recursion not returning when I set back the bar's progress or fast-forward it, but I can't figure out how to solve this issue.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Screen(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("400x50")
        MyProgressBar(self)

class MyProgressBar(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.configure(width=400, height=50)
        self.create_rectangle(0, 0, 400, 50, fill="light blue", outline="")
        self.progress = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, 0, 50, fill="cyan", outline="")
        self.place(x=0, y=0)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", lambda event: self.config_progress(event))
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event: self.resume(event.x))

 
    def config_progress(self, event):
        self.delete(self.progress)
        self.progress = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, event.x, 50, fill="cyan", outline="")

    def resume(self, event):
        print(event)
        print("calling resume")
        if event >= 400:
            print("returning")
            return
        self.delete(self.progress)
        self.progress = self.create_rectangle(0, 0, event, 50, fill="cyan", outline="")
        self.after(2000, self.resume, event + 10)

screen = Screen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: As you guessed the `after` loop never exits (note `after` loops aren't really recursive). To fix that store the value returned using `self.id = self.after(...)` and then you can use `self.after_cancel(self.id)` to stop that `after` call from happening. For more info look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25704027/11106801)