# Using tkinter Text widgets to display the result

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I am tring to pick some 6 numbers in a range randomly and display them using `Text` widget.

The program is supposed to write one line every second
but the output is just one line (the last line)..

**Code:**

```py
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

wn=Tk()
wn.geometry("300x300")

for i in range(5):
    loto=random.sample(range(1,30),6)
    mytext=Text(wn,bg="pink",width=30,height=200)
    mytext.pack()
    mytext.insert('1.0', loto,"\n")
    mytext = mytext.get('1.0', 'end')
    time.sleep(1)

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use just `time.sleep(1)` to see update every second you have to update the main window. And you're creating like 5 `Text` widget every 1 seconds, one is sufficient. Just have one outside the loop and update it.

**Something like this..**

```
from tkinter import*
import random, time

wn=Tk()
wn.geometry("300x300")

mytext=Text(wn,bg="pink",width=30,height=200)
mytext.pack()

for i in range(5):
    loto = random.sample( range(1,30),6)
    mytext.insert('end', str(loto) + '\n')
    wn.update()
    time.sleep(1)

wn.mainloop()
```

Although, this is not the recommended way of looping something in tkinter but for small loops and these kind of purposes it is fine to use. If you plan to loop something large like updating a lot of Text, widgets and images in tkinter then use `after()` function ( [How to use after()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753632/tkinter-how-to-use-after-method) ). In short `after` calls the function in every given interval so by putting it in a function it keeps on calling the same function till you stop it, can be stopped by different ways [see this post on how to stop after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776718/how-do-i-stop-tkinter-after-function).

**With use of `after():`**

```
from tkinter import*
import random, time

wn=Tk()
wn.geometry("300x300")

mytext=Text(wn,bg="pink",width=30,height=200)
mytext.pack()

def update(c=0):
    if c < 5:                                   # Runs 5 times
        loto = random.sample( range(1,30),6)
        mytext.insert('end', str(loto) + '\n')
        wn.after(1000, update, c+1)             # after( ms, func, args )

update()                                        # Called the function once

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Saad..Your answer is help full..and now .how can I add/increase your reputation?

Comment: By accepting and upvoting the best answer to your question. : )