# Stopping the execution of a continuous function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, serial-port, pyserial

In my tkinter program, i plan to have a button to read serial data.
This will begin the execution of a function called readSerial() that will grab data and display them to a textbox.

This is the function:

```
#this function reads the incoming data and inserts them into a text frame
def readSerial():
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    text.insert("end", ser_bytes)
    if vsb.get()[1]==1.0:
       text.see("end")
    root.after(100, readSerial)
```

And we're calling it from a button. Then it starts executing continuously, in intervals - specified in the `root.after(100, readSerial)` line

However, my serial device (arduino) will have other modes of operation.
So i will also have another button that will command the arduino to stop talking.

Since the arduino will not send any data, i will have to also stop readSerial() from executing.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `after()` function calls can be stopped with `after_cancel(id)` function. Every time a `after(...)` function is called it returns an after id that can be used to stop the function call. You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777453/10364425).

```py
...

after_ids = {}

# this function reads the incoming data and inserts them into a text frame
def readSerial():
    ser_bytes = ser.readline()
    ser_bytes = ser_bytes.decode("utf-8")
    text.insert("end", ser_bytes)
    if vsb.get()[1] == 1.0:
        text.see("end")
    after_ids[1] = root.after(100, readSerial)


def stopSerial():
    if after_ids.get(1) is not None:
        root.after_cancel(after_ids[1])

...
```